# Implicit declaration error while try to build the app for the instruments

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I try to find the memory leaks in my app via the instruments in Xcode, so I try to call the instruments from the Xcode (call Profile button instead of run).

The issue is that I can't run the instruments because of several errors in method:

```
-(void)createWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height).size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    [self deleteImage];
    [self createWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

For example:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContext' is invalid in C99
```

But when I try to just run the app - this errors are become warnings - and the app run normally. I can't find the root cause of the issue - any help?

Comment: `CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height).size` - wat? isn't that simply the same as `size`?

Comment: Are you certain that source file can see the `UIKit.h` header file (I assume it's in the prefix file anyway)?

Comment: i write your code it is not giving me this error. it is giving me error on [self createWithCGImage:image]; which is fixed by writing this  [self createWithCGImage:(__bridge UIImage *)(image)];

Comment: It's not my code - it is the panoramaGL framework sources